# Errant sqlite3 db.lock blocking web deploy in VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm having a continuing problem in Visual Studio 2017 where every time I go to publish my ASP.Net C# web application, visual studio generates a sql lite folder containing a db.lock file which stops it from copying the files into the deployment. I'm not using sql lite, I have a connection string in my web.config to connect to an externally hosted SQL database. I can delete the file and the generated folders under .vs, but it is auto-generated again once I open the solution after a few moments. I've already excluded the folder from my git repository.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this once and for all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to add the following code within the `<Project>` section of website.publishproj file in the folder:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>.vs</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```